# WCF - The identity check failed for the outgoing message

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security

I have a wcf service that run on a server. I have  two clients that connecs to the service. We use username and password to authenticate the client.But I recreated the certificate  in the same location as previous using `PluralSight Software`
[image]

But after configuring  the client to connect to the service I have got following error.

`The identity check failed for the outgoing message. The expected identity is 'identity(http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/right/possessproperty: http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/thumbprint)' for the  target endpoint`

I got the above error when I tried to login to the service. I have shared my configuration details here.. any help would be appreciated.

**CLIENT APP.CONFIG VIA WCF CONFIGURATION EDITOR**

[image: Client App.config via WCF configuration edit-Bindings-1]
[image: Client App.config via WCF configuration edit-Bindings-2]
[image: Client App.config via WCF configuration edit-Endpoints-1]
[image: Client App.config via WCF configuration edit-Endpoints-2]

**SERVICE WEB.CONFIG VIA WCF CONFIGURATION EDITOR**

[image: Service web.config via WCF configuration edit]

[image: Service web.config via WCF configuration edit-Endpoints-1]

[image: Service web.config via WCF configuration edit-Endpoints-2]

[image: Service web.config via WCF configuration edit-Bindings-1]

[image: Service web.config via WCF configuration edit-Bindings-2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. This happens because if you create a new certificate on server which wcf service host then you need to update the service reference in client application. so it will update the app.config file of the client application with latest identity value.